# combinations of boolean variables - no repeats

Tags: python

I am trying to have python give me the combinations of a list of names with either a negative or a positive associated, for example

```
[['A+','A-'],['B+','B-']] -> [['A+','B+'],['A+','B-'],['A-','B+'],['A-','B-']]
```

I can't figure out a way to use itertools to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as follows:

```
from itertools import product

a = [['A+','A-'],['B+','B-']]

print list(product(*a))

[OUTPUT]
[('A+', 'B+'), ('A+', 'B-'), ('A-', 'B+'), ('A-', 'B-')]
```

Answer (score 1):

just iterate through [0] and [1] separately

```
outputList = []
for a in inputList[0]:
    for b in inputList[1]:
        outputList.append([a,b])
```